# Scala: Incorrect element order when storing dataframe to CosmosDB in Databricks

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, connector

I am using the Apache Spark to Azure Cosmos DB connector to store a dataframe in scala to CosmosDB.
This works but there is an odd thing with the element order in the document that is stored.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = new StructType()
.add("a", StringType, true)   
.add("b", StringType, true) 
.add("c",                 
    new StructType()
      .add("d", StringType, true)
      .add("e", StringType, true)
      .add("f", StringType, true)
)

val dataDS = Seq("""
{
"a": "a",
"b": "b",
"c": {
    "d": "d",
    "e": "e",
    "f": "f"
}
}""").toDS()

val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json(dataDS)                    
println(df.printSchema())
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).cosmosDB(writeConfig)
```

generates this document in CosmosDB

```
{
"a": "a",
"b": "b",
"c": {
    "d": "d",
    "e": "e",
    "f": "f"
},
"id": "7c2ef8b9-86a6-4aa3-b190-d5083c885ea8",
"_rid": .....
}
```

while this code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = new StructType()
.add("a", StringType, true)   
.add("beta", StringType, true)          <<-----
.add("c",                 
    new StructType()
      .add("d", StringType, true)
      .add("echo", StringType, true) .  <<-----
      .add("f", StringType, true)
)

val dataDS = Seq("""
{
"a": "a",
"beta": "b",                            <<-----
"c": {
    "d": "d",
    "echo": "e",                        <<-----
    "f": "f"
}
}""").toDS()

val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json(dataDS)                    
println(df.printSchema())
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).cosmosDB(writeConfig)
```

generates this document in CosmosDB

```
{
"a": "a",
"c": {
    "d": "d",
    "f": "f",
    "echo": "e"                                 <<-----
},
"id": "509c6c94-139a-4b73-a2dc-1ff424519adb",
"beta": "b",                                    <<-----
"_rid": .....
}
```

Why is it so that the order of the elements are modified in the two examples. I want the structure of the document to be as in the first example. I am not sure why chaning e->echo and b->beta changes the document structure in CosmosDB.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening and what can be done to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure why it happens, but your data looks like a **JSON** and as such, order should not matter at all. It is any reason for you to be concerned about that, or it is not a **JSON**? - also, `printSchema` as the name says, it prints. Thus, you don't need to call `println(df.printSchema)` it will print the **Unit** element which is `()`.

Answer (score 2):

Cosmos DB doesn't really store JSON as JSON, but it decomposes it into ARS structure:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/a-technical-overview-of-azure-cosmos-db/

When you ask for a JSON then it recreates it on the fly. More details on internal representation can be found here in the "Documents as Trees" section:

http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol8/p1668-shukla.pdf

Why preserving the order of properties is important for you?